# How can I replace a text with a text which contains a Quotation Mark

Tags: powershell

I want to replace a piece of text, using powershell, but this piece of text contains a quotation mark.
The text I want to replace is shown below here:

```
-replace '<photo>', '<image url="'
```

Unfortunatly this is a problem because I can't use the quotation mark. Does someone has a solution for this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote with `

```
-replace '<photo>', '<image url=`"'
```